# Customize Ribbon menu in android

Tags: android, menu

i want to customize Ribbon menu (https://github.com/jaredsburrows/RibbonMenu) , the original menu is showing only a ListView, when I hit the menu item. I would like to open new intent after keypress, not only listview. I tried something like this, but this opens a new intent without the Ribbon menu. My purpose is toopen new intent or activity inside this menu - like a listview. Can u help me?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
            {
                switch (position)
                {
                case 0:
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class);
                    MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
                    //final String[] items = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
                    //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
                //  list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    final String[] items1 = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items1);
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                    break;


                }
                rbmView.hideMenu();
            }
```

Comment: Hello, what would you like to do exactly?